# iOS Firebase push messaging not receiving

Tags: ios, firebase-cloud-messaging, push, silentpush

I have been doing to integrate Firebase Push Notification.(Silent messaging)
I can receive data message when app is in foreground state.
But I can not receive any messaging when app is background and closed state.
I want to receive and handle messages when receiver is in closed state.
If I can receive not handled messages when I open app from closed state then it would be ok.
But Just now I can receive only app is in foreground state.
If I close app and send messages. And then open app then does not receive any messaging.
For a few months ago, I confirmed that messages were receiving when I open app from closed state, but not now.
I am trying to fix it during a few days. 
But still does not find any solution.
How can I fix it?

I used data messaging , not push notification
And used Swift 3.

Thank you.

Comment: Which delegate method you are receiving data?

Comment: func applicationReceivedRemoteMessage(_ remoteMessage: FIRMessagingRemoteMessage)

Comment: func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)

Comment: func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)

Comment: Kindly check your payload structure , whether you have set the
content-available = true
priority = high

Comment: yes. now in foreground i can receive data message.

Comment: if i close app, and send messages on other phone, and i open receiver app, i can not know about not yet handled messages.  but in foreground, i can receive and handle all messages.